# Setting referrer/header on a redirect in Apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

I have a site with a short url domain with an A record pointing to the main site (it's a pain to change this so I'd rather not). I have special logic that needs to run when the application is accessed from the short URL.

Right now, I have Apache set up with a RewriteRule to do a 301 to the main site when you hit the short URL, but if I try to access the referrer or any sort of headers they seem to be gone. I can get around this by appending a query parameter, but I'd rather not muddy up the URL as well. Any ideas on how to set some piece of data within Apache that I can access in my Rails app to tell if the request was a result of accessing the short URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the referrer is entirely client-side, you only have two options (other than the query string):

1. Allow Rails to handle the redirect for you, instead of Apache, and store some information in the user's session.
2. Use the `cookie` RewriteRule option. RewriteRule has a cookie/CO option that allows you to send a Set-Cookie down to the browser, along with the redirect response. The format of the option is: `cookie|CO=NAME:VAL:domain[:lifetime[:path]]`. See the [RewriteRule documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule) for more details.

Comment: I tried setting the cookie, but I'm not seeing it being set after the page renders:

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName shorturl.com

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{http_host} ^shorturl\.com [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://longurl.com/$1 [R=301,NC,CO=shorturl:yes:.longurl.com:/]
</VirtualHost>

Comment: @rdeshpande You forgot the expiration param. You're specifying `/` as the expiration, which is probably making it expire immediately.

Answer (score 0):

For strictly performance reasons, I would stick with Apache doing the redirect so it doesn't need to go into the Rack (aka spend more time). Thus I would set a cookie on the [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule) and destroy the cookie once you detect the redirect.